# How to hide <option> tag if value is null?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pdo

```
    <select name="" id="pftb">
  <option value="<?php echo $pf1;?>"><?php echo $pf1;?></option>

<option value="<?php echo is_null($pf2) ? "" : $pf2; ?>" ><?php echo is_null($pf2) ? "" : $pf2; ?></option>

<option value="<?php echo is_null($pf3) ? "" : $pf3; ?>"><?php echo is_null($pf3) ? "" : $pf3; ?></option>
    </select>
```

I'm fetching data from DB to show it in the dropdown above.

If the value is `null`,i.e. if the DB returns `null` value, it shows an empty option in the drop down like in the picture below:

[The img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Njn.png)

As shown in the image, first option is showing as it has value
but it also shows second and third option with no value, just blank.

What I want to achieve is to hide the second and third option if it has no value and to show it if the value is valid (not `null`).

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share more details - what have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using CSS

```
<option value="<?php echo is_null($pf2) ? "" : $pf2; ?>" style="<?php echo is_null($pf2) ? "display:none" : "display:block"; ?>"><?php echo is_null($pf2) ? "" : $pf2; ?></option>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only generate the option when the $value is not empty. Use this logic for rest of the variables.

```
  <select name="" id="pftb">
  <?php
  if (!empty($value)){
  ?>
   <option value='<?=$value?>'><?=$value?></option>
  <?php }
  ?>
```

You can use `css` to hide the option as well.